# dollar sign in javascript methods

Tags: javascript, syntax

Can someone explain the usage of the dollar sign here..

```
var updateProgressDiv = $get('updateProgressDiv');
```

scroll down to the functions.. 
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/05/ajaxnet_example_using_an_updat.html

Comment: It's not C#, its javascript - similar but different ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's merely part of the function name -- $ is allowed in JavaScript identifiers, so ($get) is the full function name.

Comment: This is not right based on the example madcolor sent, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

This is asp.net ajax shortcut:
$get Shortcut Method

Provides a shortcut to the getElementById method of the Sys.UI.DomElement class. This member is static and can be invoked without creating an instance of the class.

[See more information about](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ClientReference/Global/GetShortCutMethod.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

$get is jQuery syntax for fetching an element.  It has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: It's not jQuery -- jQuery would be $.get(). I think this is some ASP support script.